# Tizen Studio DevTools ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT Issue

Tags: angular, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, tizen-studio

I'm trying to implement Clover cloud pay on my web app built by tizen studio.
The Tizen Studio only builds on Chromium version 56 and this old version blocks https connections to use Clover sdk.
Based on my research I did change chrome settings flags (e.g. enable-quic, allow-insecure-localhost, etc), generate my own certificates to run it localhost, give tizen authorization, and update package.json to "ng serve --open --ssl true" but nothing helped me to get rid of this error.
Please advice!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chromium version 56 is pretty old. Sometimes old versions might throw error ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT as mentioned in :
https://www.clickssl.net/blog/how-to-fix-err_bad_ssl_client_auth_cert-for-google-chrome

Please try updating the Chromium version using Tizen Studio's Package Manager (which looks like https://developer.tizen.org/sites/default/files/images/overview_package_manager.png)

Installing 6.0 or above version package(s) should help resolve the error.
Once installed, rebuild your Web App for the installed package version, on Tizen Studio and re-check the issue.
If still facing the same error, kindly update/post here with additional details like the base URL/server that you are trying to access from your Web App. Thanks.